# What are the backend service for flutter?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, backend

I am confused in choosing database service for my flutter application. I started using firebase but as it is based on NoSQL , But if i am getting the need for rows and columns for my data which backend service should i use!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on how you want to access the data. If you're wanting to stream and push notifications, I would stick with Firebase. If you just need to get and post data, focus more on api implementation. With a solid rest api, you can change up your database/backend all you want and just have to update the api, not your app.

I, personally, suggest searching around for data modeling techniques in Firebase. Check out the Fireship channel on youtube. In his channel's videos, search for `modeling` and you'll find a ton of info on Firebase data modeling. Many will reference Angular, but the techniques are the same.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you want to user Rows and Columns but want a service like Firebase. Well, here's a SQL alternative to Firebase.

#### [Supabase](https://supabase.com/)

Typical SQL DB and works just like Firebase. Below is official docs of Flutter and Supabase which you can use to get started :)

#### [Flutter x Supabase Docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-flutter)

Cheers!

Comment: thanks means a lot